# Make SSIS foreach loop rescan folder after completion

Tags: ssis

I have a foreach loop that executes for each file in a folder. If files are added to this folder after the foreach loop has already started, it skips these files. Is there a way to make the foreach loop check for new files after it completes it's current cycle?

Eg. So lets say there are 5 files in the folder when the foreach loop starts and 2 more files are added. How do I get the foreach loop to process these without having to start the package again?

Comment: Modifying the thing you're currently iterating over introduces lots of bugs. To save yourself the headaches, just run it again or schedule it to run more frequently.

Comment: Alternatively, add in logic to move the processed files to a different location.  That way, the next time you execute the process, the files that arrived after execution started will be picked up.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The files are already getting moved to another directory as it gets processed. It is one of that "but why" requests... The job already runs every 30 minutes so will have to do.